# Why can't Aggregate and lookup functions be used in query parameter expressions in SSRS?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

I'm using an if to run one query if the user selects all from a multivalued parameter, and the other if not. So I figured I'd compare selected parameters vs rows in the data set. 
However I get this error:

> “The expression used for the parameter 'DataSet2' in the dataset
>   'DataSet2' includes an aggregate or lookup function. Aggregate and
>   lookup functions cannot be used in query parameter expressions.”

Here's the part giving the issue:

```
IIf(Parameters!SomeOptions.Count < COUNTROWS("SOME_LIST"), ….
```

Of course supplementing the `COUNTROWS("SOME_LIST")` with `15` (the value it returns)works fine.
Anyone know why this happens, and/or any work around?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a workaround I use in the absence of an IsSelectAll flag:

1. Add another internal parameter called InternalParameter_SomeOptions.
2. Set the default value and available values to equal the same data set as SomeOptions.
3. Set your expression to =IIF(Parameters!SomeOptions.Count <> Parameters!InternalParameter_SomeOptions.Count, nothing, Join(Parameters!SomeOptions.Value, "|"))

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multi-selection parameter whose data source is a dataset and you want to know if ALL was checked, from within your REPORT Dataset (like an SQL) to filter properly, look no further!

Why does this matter?  Say you have a dataset (love datasets as data source for parameters btw, save em on the server for reuse over and over) for displaying a vendor list for users to select one or more (multi) from.  What if that list is 10,000 long.  You do NOT want to use:  WHERE VENDOR_ID IN(@VENDOR). If the list is long enough, it WILL bomb and you will have to hunt the error down in SSRS log.  So, this is one reason why we need to check if ALL was selected.

1. Create a new parameter identical to the dataset parameter(so they both use the same dataset and have the same default values), make sure to set it to multi selection and hidden (you do not want users seeing it).  I name mine ---All where --- is the name of my parameter to easily distinguish.
2. For the dataset that serves as your REPORT data, add an additional Parameter.  I like to call it @Is----AllChecked where ---- is the name of my parameter.  It is named as a boolean (1 for true, 0 for false).  In this example, it would be named @IsVendorAllChecked.
3. In the DEFAULT value expression check if the count of each REPORT parameter is the same (the one the users use and the duplicate), and return a value, like 1 if the same 0 if not. For example =IIF(Parameters!Vendor.Count = Parameters!VendorAll.Count, 1, 0)
4. In your REPORT Dataset, evaluate the parameter value and act accordingly in your SQL:   where ( (@IsVendorAllChecked = 1 and vendor_id = vendor_id) or (@IsVendorAllChecked = 0 and vendor_id in(@Vendor)))

@Vendor obviously being the parameter the user interacts.

Always wanted to contribute.
SE: Report Builder check if all was selected
SE: Report Builder how to check if all was selected
SE: Report Builder parameter query expression cannot use aggregates